# BCC all recipients with EmailMultiAlternatives

Tags: python, django

I have this method that I use to send mass emails:

```
def send_mass_html_mail(datatuple, fail_silently=False, user=None, password=None, connection=None):
    connection = connection or get_connection(username=user, password=password, fail_silently=fail_silently)
    messages = []
    for subject, text, html, from_email, recipient in datatuple:
        message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text, from_email, recipient)
        message.attach_alternative(html, 'text/html')
        messages.append(message)
    return connection.send_messages(messages)
```

I want to be able to BCC everyone. That is, instead of having everyone's email in the recipients, I would like to hide everyone's email address.

I tried to just make the to email blank and just add all of the recipients to the BCC kwargs, but it still puts everyone's email in the TO field.

```
def send_mass_html_mail(datatuple, fail_silently=False, user=None, password=None, connection=None):
    connection = connection or get_connection(username=user, password=password, fail_silently=fail_silently)
    messages = []
    for subject, text, html, from_email, recipient in datatuple:
        message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text, from_email, [], bcc=recipient)
        message.attach_alternative(html, 'text/html')
        messages.append(message)
    return connection.send_messages(messages)
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to send each email individually?

**Edit:**

I wound up just iterating through the recipient list and sending off emails separately. I don't know why it didn't work, but I couldn't afford to spend hours on this. It works for me because the app sends emails to a max of 25 people at a time.

I still don't know why this didn't work. Does `EmailMultiAlternatives` need something in the TO field? I looked at the `EmailMultiAlternatives` and the `EmailMessage` source code, and it seems like it'd send emails without anyone in that field. There's something off about my code, but I can't identify what.

Comment: I would recommend using https://www.mandrill.com/ or http://www.mailgun.com/. That will also allow you to send personalised emails without the recipients seeing each other. I used mandrill for my newsletter app with great results.

Comment: Your code looks like it's already sending each email individually? Or is `recipient` actually multiple addresses?

Answer (score 4):

You are using uppercase BCC. It should be lowercase. I'm surprised that the current code sends any emails at all at the moment.

```
message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text, from_email, [], bcc=recipient_list)
```